# How to get the code of a method from its Class

Tags: java, class

I am working with this awesome little piece of code, and I need some help figuring it out.

Basically it has a big byte array, which is used to load a new class:

```
    Class class = class1.loadClass(name, byteArray);
    class.getMethod("run", new Class[0]).invoke(null, new Object[0]);
```

This is loadClass:

```
    public Class<?> loadClass(String paramString, byte[] paramArrayOfByte) throws ClassNotFoundException
        return defineClass(paramString, paramArrayOfByte, 0, paramArrayOfByte.length);
```

And then it calls the 'run' in this class. Now, besides this being an awesome way to hide your classes, how do I get a look into this class? I have the actual class in 'class', but I don't get further than  the attributes and their values and the function names. I want to know what 'run' actually does. Is there any way to somehow print the content of this method or whatever? Or maybe I can transform the byte array containing the class in something readable?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to add source for `class1` to derive anything meaningful from this custom ClassLoader descendant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you write this `byteArray` in a `.class` file and open it with a Java Decompiler tool (like jd-gui) ?

Comment: Thanks! (while hitting my head for not even thinking about writing the byte array to a file) 
So, I wrote it to a .class file and used jd-gui to decompile it, works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking how to read a class file into something meaninful.So basically you are asking for it to be decompiled like JD-Decompiler .Also,the .class files are loaded in the memory by the classloader.
I would suggest you take a dump of the .class file and write it in the file using ByteArrayOutputStream  and ObjectOutputStream .Then decompile it using any decompiler software.

Please note that this process does not guarantee any accuracy of the source file decompiled..